AN-225 dimensions?
Does anyone know the dimensions of the AN-225 tail or where I can find them? I am doing a research/personal development project, and my focus is on improving my CAD modelling skills. I am deeply interested in aviation and thought it would be cool to model the AN-225 tail for my project.
Thank you!

Not an answer, but some ideas: Knowing the main dimensions, it is easy to derive the other ones using a photo or a drawing. You can also use the photo or the drawing as a reference image in your CAD software, or download a 3D model and study it.

You can download magazine “Аэрохобби” 1/1992 (https://readli.net/aerohobbi-1992-01/). There are couple schemes that you may use and also description about sizes.
